# file_get_contents fails to get a link with some perso-arabic characters

Tags: php

this link works ok when i open it in my browser

but when i do this

```
$link = 'http://www.bama.ir/خريد-خودرو/?ac411129-3-0-0-0-0-0-900000000-1/کادنزا-كیا';
echo  file_get_contents($link);
```

i get

```
    ( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.bama.ir/خريد-خودرو/?ac411129-3-0-0-0-0-0-900000000-1/کادنزا-كیا):
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
```

i think it's becuz of the characters at the end of the link (it works ok if i replace them with latin characters )

is there a urlencode like function for file_get_contents  ?

-----------------  EDIT --------------------------

```
$link = urlencode('http://www.bama.ir/خريد-خودرو/?ac411129-3-0-0-0-0-0-900000000-1/کادنزا-كیا');
echo  file_get_contents("$link");
```

result

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bama.ir%2F%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%2F%3Fac411129-3-0-0-0-0-0-900000000-1%2F%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%86%D8%B2%D8%A7-%D9%83%DB%8C%D8%A7): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 12
```

Comment: Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: @sectus - Should put that in as a response as that is the answer.

Comment: @max, you should read documentation carefully. *This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL*

Answer (score 1):

The link can be converted using `urlencode` to a string that `file_get_contents` understands. For example:

```
echo file_get_conents("http://www.bama.ir/%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88/?ac411129-3-0-0-0-0-0-900000000-1/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%86%D8%B2%D8%A7-%D9%83%DB%8C%D8%A7");
```

Comment: Why not pass the URL to `urlencode`, then pass that string to `file_get_contents`?

Comment: @max: From the code you provided, I presume that you are hard coding this link. I tested the code that I showed in the example and I was successfully able to get a response from the server. Could you verify that your code is being properly uploaded in the first place?

Comment: yes i've tried your code and it works fine but when i do it i get error , look at my edit ... i dont know why it encodes the http part !

Comment: @max: Yeah, I just realized the problem. I think you may need to use `parse_url` and manually reassemble the URL again after having encoded the string past the initial http://<host>.

Comment: your encode result is very different from what i get ! how did you do it ? even if i delete the http part it doesn't work ... there is `%2F` right after `.ir` in my url

Comment: The URL that I used there was generated using Google Chrome, I was trying to be quick with an answer. The urlencode function is not as smart unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok. You should use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) but not for whole link, for its part only.

```
$link = 'http://www.bama.ir/'
        . urlencode('خريد-خودرو')
        . '/?ac411129-3-0-0-0-0-0-900000000-1/'
        . urlencode('کادنزا-كیا'); 

// http://www.bama.ir/%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88/?ac411129-3-0-0-0-0-0-900000000-1/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%86%D8%B2%D8%A7-%D9%83%DB%8C%D8%A7

echo  file_get_contents($link);
```